# Android Studio: How do I fix my AVD termination issue?

Tags: java, android, configuration

Every time I run the android studio emulator, I get this error message:

"The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_32 has terminated".

I have tried numerous things. I've tried turning on Hyper-V. I've checked and I have plenty of disk space. I have HAXXM turned on. I am using the correct version of the API in the ADK Manager. I'm not sure what to do. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for AVD terminated:

1. In directory `C:\User\(your user name)\.android`.
2. Add file AdvancedFeatures.ini, add 2 lines then save it.

```
Vulkan = off 
GLDirectMem = on
```